# Adding comments to my webpage

Tags: comments, facebook-comments, app-id

I'm trying to add the comments thingy to my page. I followed the directions here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

I have no idea what URL I should set ; I tried my webpage URL and I get an error ("page could not be contacted"). I also tried my facebook page, no error but no comments are published.

I read somewhere else that I need an AppID, so I went to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ which redirects to my page.

I also tried the moderation URL http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments but all I get is a generic error.

I guess I'm missing something so obvious that it's not documented.

Can anybody help????

TIA

greg

Comment: Is your page behind a password? Use FB's Debugger - http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - and it will show you exactly what FB sees when they go to your page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

No password for this page: 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.legrandtestdeslumieres.fr%2Fcomparateur.html

The debugger gives me a lot of warning that mean nothing to me. Is the URL ok?

greg

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need is [Open Graph tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) (this is why you are seeing the "Open Graph  Warnings" message on the [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)).

To easily generate these tags for your page, go to Step 2 on the [Like Button developer page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), where you fill out a few items and get the code for your tags. Insert these tags into the `<head>` of your page. The `og:url` is one of the most important, and having it missing could be why you are getting errors.

Then, follow the steps on the [Comments developer page.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

[You can always try looking through this tutorial](http://www.ruhanirabin.com/easy-steps-to-facebook-connect-comment-box-how-to/) as well.

Comment: The tutorial says:

Create a Facebook Application for your website. This step is required and all the fields must be filled up

However the setup link always leads to my home page so I cannot have an AppID...

Comment: Are you registered as a Facebook Developer? https://developers.facebook.com/ or https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: How do I register? when I click  http://developers.facebook.com/apps I see my home page. I can't see any way to register...

Comment: What 'homepage'? Do you mean your News Feed? When you go to developers.facebook.com, do you see "Login" in the upper right hand corner, or do you see your name, or what?

Comment: I see my facebook homepage: my picture, my wall, a "logout" button in the upper right, "recent activities", etc